# ionic Push notification error 500 when testing on real ios Device

Tags: ios, push-notification, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Push Notification for my app. Everything goes right. I configured both android and ios environment. The test goes well on both  Nexus4 and iPad4 devices when running from command line

```
$ ionic run ios --device
$ ionic run android
```

but when I test it using a generated build using xCode (on Test Flight) I can register successfully but I can not push to ios device.

I tried to use direct push via ionic push interface, I get a 500 error, without any explaination.

Please any suggestion about that?

Comment: Same here.  Figure it out?

Comment: That was with the old api for ionic push. I contact them about this issue and after few time they fix it since a 500 error is from the ionic server side.
But now try with the new api, if still have a 500 error you should contact their support or try posting a new question on any relative forum stackoverflow, ionic github project, ...

Comment: Support has been 'silent'.  Just sent the 3rd email today.

Answer (score 0):

So was able to answer my own problem.  During Ionic Alpha it was possible to send an array of tokens in a single API call.   That does not appear to work anymore, instead I'm now doing a forEach and making an API push call for each token in question.  It's slow, and it will not scale, but the 500 error is gone.

Comment: I don't think so, I am sending notifications using an array of tokens. I even use array for a single item. and it's working fine on both alpha (previously) and beta (actually). I don't know which language you are using on the backend for sending invitations. but You may need to be sure it's a strings array not a related type like collections or array of objects.

Comment: So your large single array.  Does it look like this [token,token,token] or a multi-dimension array[[token],[token,[token]]?

Comment: a single array [token,token,token]

Comment: I created a new app within the Ionic dashboard, moved my certs, updated api tokens, etc.  Now it works as expected.